# Numbering all lines in a presentation

Tags: beamer, line-numbering

I would like everyline of a presentation to be numbered. Like the `lineno` package will do.

I tried the following but it does not print line numbers. I don't see why, I know there are some `\par` caveats. But I don't really understand them.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[mathlines]{lineno}

\linenumbers

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

    A floating line

    \begin{theorem}
        Some line in a theorem
    \end{theorem}

    \begin{linenomath}
        \begin{eqnarray*}
            x + y 
        \end{eqnarray*} 
    \end{linenomath}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the `lineno` manual, line numbers do not automatically apply to boxed material. In `beamer` each slide is typeset as a box, hence no numbers. Thus you will need to add `\internallinenumbers` and possibly appropriate `\resetlinenumber[<number>]` statement to each frame:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lineno}
\linenumbers
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \internallinenumbers
  A line

  Another line

  A very long line.
   A very long line.
    A very long line.
     A very long line.
      A very long line.
       A very long line.

  Some maths: $y = mx + c$

  \begin{linenomath*}
    \begin{equation}
      y = mx + c
    \end{equation}
  \end{linenomath*}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you'll notice, the way `beamer` sets display maths (and other stuff) 'behind the scenes' means that the numbering can be a bit odd. If just numbering text is acceptable then

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{lineno}
\linenumbers
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{internallinenumbers}
  A line

  Another line

  A very long line.
   A very long line.
    A very long line.
     A very long line.
      A very long line.
       A very long line.

  Some maths: $y = mx + c$
  \end{internallinenumbers}

  \begin{equation}
      y = mx + c
  \end{equation}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

is rather better.

[image]